# Is my device not support appCompatActivity?

Tags: android, android-studio, appcompatactivity

Im new here, Im sorry if my question is not good.

I have made an android app with appcompatactivity, but if I run it in my device(android 4.2.2), it always stopped. Thankyou for your answer.

Comment: you should debug your application. Then you will find the exact error.

Comment: I do not think your crash is for appcompactactivity. Check your error log in Android Monitor. If you do not understand it then put it to your question.

Comment: I think my error in appcompat because if I change "extends appcompatactivity" with "extends activity", there is no error

Comment: try my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36760928/is-my-device-not-support-appcompatactivity/36760972#36760972) and see if that works.

Comment: put your log in your question then

Comment: @RohitArya I have used 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'

Comment: post your error log then.

Comment: Oh @RohitArya your answer is can make my app run, but I change it to 17.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your device meets your described SDK version at `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="xx"
    android:targetSdkVersion="YY" />
```

So your device meets at least version xx example API 11